# Conga Composer - Having a page editable in the Word Document when WPD=1

Tags: conga

We are using the Conga Composer to generate Word documents, one of the requirements is to make the Word document read-only for which the parameter WPD=1 parameter is being used. An addendum to this requirement is that we need a page to be editable in the while the remaining document remains read only. Having TEXTBOX as a prefix to the merge field does make the field editable, however we need a whole page editable. Please suggest if there are any work around ways to achieve this.